# Adding space after symbol if there doesn't already exist a space?

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I need to replace all instances of commas in my file where there isn't already a space after the comma.

For example, the following needs to change. From this:

```
some function(int x,int y, int z)
{
    // code
}
```

To this:

```
some function(int x, int y, int z)
{
    // code
}
```

Notice the spaces after the commas where there wasn't already a space. How can I do this to apply to a 1,000+ line file of code using Sublime?

Comment: Use a negative lookahead.

Comment: You could replace `,\s*` with ```, ```, but that may affect commas in more places than you'd like.

Answer (score 3):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to open the **Search and Replace**, enable *Regular Expression*..

Using Negative Lookahead:

```
Find: ,(?!\s)
Replace: , 
          ^
          |___ space character
```

Or a basic regular expression:

```
Find: ,([^\s])
Replace: , \1
```